# Inheritance with no additional data members

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider this code:

```
class Basic {
public:
   Basic() { ... }
   Basic(const Basic& other) { ... }
   virtual ~Basic() { ... }

   virtual void foo() = 0;
private:
   int x, y, z;
};

class DerivedA : public Basic {
public:
   DerivedA() :  { ... }
   virtual ~DerivedA() { ... }

   virtual void foo() { ... }
}

class DerivedB : public Basic {
public:
   DerivedB() { ... }
   virtual ~DerivedB() { ... }

   virtual void foo() { ... }
}
```

Actually, `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` classes have no additional data members, their only purpose is to override pure virtual `foo` function from `Basic` class.

I want to implement **copy-constructor** and **`operator=`** for both `Derived` classes.

**My plan is:**

1) Copy-constructor:

Implementing copy-constructors in Derived classes like that:

```
DerivedA(const DerivedA& other) : Basic(other) {
   // Do nothing
}
DerivedB(const DerivedB& other) : Basic(other) {
   // Do nothing
}
```

2) Assignment-operator:

Implementing swap for `Basic` class :

```
void swap(Basic& other) {
  std::swap(x, other.x);
  std::swap(y, other.y);
  std::swap(z, other.z);
}
```

Overloading operator= for 'Derived' classes :

```
DerivedA& operator=(const DerivedA& other) {
  Derived tmp(other);
  (*this).swap(tmp);
  return (*this);
}
```

The same for `DerivedB`

Now my question: is it a good practice? Should I implement swap for both Derived classes? Are there any better ways to implement such methods in this kind of inheritance? Is my architecture good enough to be well-supported by others?

**p.s.** sorry for my English.

Comment: If your code works as desired, but you just want to have it reviewed for best practices or alternative ways of accomplishing the same task, maybe migrate it to Stack Exchanges Code Review section.

Comment: What if someone swap()s two derived-class instances which are not of the same type?  Or a reference to one Basic and one DerivedA?  It seems that having swap() defined for a base class is fraught.

Comment: Actually, the programming subsite is better for higher-level design questions. This is clearly not a code review question.

Answer (score 3):

Let me offer an alternate suggestion: Use the default copy constructor and copy assignment operators and let the compiler do the work for you! Your class doesn't have any shallow state so the default versions will do exactly what you want, and are much more likely to be generated correctly by the compiler than you are to not miss a copy-paste somewhere, introducing a subtle bug.